# Mysql load data skipped too many record

Tags: mysql

I got this csv exported from a mysql table in this way

```
select *  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/myfile.csv'   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FROM bouncemap
```

I need to use sed to replace the ip addresses with **start *** value in this csv and replace some other bounce code always with **star *** char.
The problem is that after using sed on this csv file, I try to import it into mysql's table in this way

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

and the import process skipped more than 70% of the record.
I've noticed that if I export the table as csv and then re-import in the mysql table, **without** using sed everything is fine and all the record are imported.
I have also noticed that if I replace the ip address with **hash #** char instead than star the number of **not** imported record rise like 80%.
I am using mysql 5.1 on debian 6.0.5

Any idea or suggestion?
Cheers

Comment: Why are you bothering with this? You could just do your changes via SQL queries.

Comment: I've tried but I prefer use tool like sed,awk in these case.
Also because I am not still so good at mysql queries :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys the problem was that some record was too long and mysql added some extra **\n** char
to the record during the export process.
So it means that I got some row with one record empty.
So my colleague suggested to use this little trick

```
select bouncetype, replace (bouncereason,'\n','')  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' from bouncemap;
```

**replace** in this case change \n newline with nothing also if the line is too long.

So I managed to use sed for manipulate the file extracted, then imported it
and mysql didn't complaint :D